# Installing vlc web plugin for chrome on mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, vlc, npapi

I want to install the vlc web plugin for chrome on  my mac (Mountain Lion) . I could succesfully do it on Windows by just selecting web plugin at the time of vlc installation. However, on a mac I think the plugin comes as a seperate package. Can someone please tell me how to do it as I have failed after several tries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no compatible VLC browser plugin available on the Mac at this point. We re-wrote it over the cause of the last year and will re-release an entirely new version this spring along with VLC 2.2 for desktop platforms.

Comment: VLC 2.2.0 seems to have been released; I just got it from the official download page. Is the plugin supposed to work now? Because it is not showing up for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

Until the stable version is released, you can install a recent **nightly webplugin** from http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/macosx-intel/?C=N;O=A.

It may have bugs, but it works for the few instances I've used it.

Comment: I installed this nightly build, is there anything I need to do for the Chrome plugin to work? I still don't see it listed on chrome://plugins. (Using Chrome, Mac OSX Yosemite, VLC Nightly Build 2.2.0-rc2)

Comment: You need to download the web plugin, e.g. VLC-webplugin-20150225-0535.dmg. Once you open it, you will see a shortcut to the Internet Plugins directory to which you must drag and drop the "VLC Plugin.plugin." Restart Chrome and you will see it listed in chrome://plugins/. Keep in mind that, at present, NPAPI plugins (such as this one) will are scheduled to be removed completely in September 2015.

Answer (score 1):

This currently works.  Here is a step by step guide:

1. In your browser go to http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/macosx-intel/
   and download the latest `VLC-webplugin-*.dmg`.
   *Today the latest file appears to be this `VLC-webplugin-20150922-0538.dmg`*
2. Open the `.dmg` file (double click, and a popup window will appear), drag the `VLC Plugin.plugin` to the `Internet Plugins shortcut`; This location is really `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/`
3. In the Chrome address bar type `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` and press Enter/Return.
4. You will see a list of settings, with a blue link to disable or enable.
   Click 'Enable', under 'Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows', (this Enables NPAPI Mac, Windows. It enables the use of NPAPI plugins.)
5. Restart Chrome
6. In the Chrome address bar type `chrome://plugins/` and press Enter/Return

You should now see 'VLC Web Plugin - Version: 2.2.2'

Comment: @user3392740 Here is another link that explains it further: http://www.vboxcomm.com/enable-vlc-web-plugin-in-google-chrome-npapi.html?tmpl=component

Comment: Those instructions are already out of date; the flag in step 3 doesn't exist in current versions of Chrome (45+), as NPAPI support has been removed completely.